# Dojo doesn't seems to recognize custom Resource Bundle

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I have defined a **json** file in which I have all of my properties.
when I try to access these properties in my code, it shows the property is null.
I also tried accessing one of the properties form the pre-defined bundle `colors` in dojo folder and was able to access it.
when tried adding a property in the same colors.js file and tried accessing it, it again showed that the property is `null`.

Any pointer would be of real help.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a Javascript object definition, so you don't include JSON file but JavaScript file

Static:

```
<script src="js/config.js"></script>

var config = {
    someKey: 'Some Value'
}
```

Dynamic (NLS bundles):

```
require(["dojo/i18n!myproject/nls/messages"], function(messages) {.... })

define({
  root: {
    someKey: 'Some message in some languange',  
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help Web... but it was some other issue.. i was not giving the commas between two properties... :)